# Creating a PHP Web app from scratch using Slim as Architecture

Tags: php, url-rewriting, url-routing, slim

This is my long quest to develop web apps using core PHP and follow the best possible practices and not using a framework. I have achieved many things by structuring my project a better way. However ...getting a clean URL is often a problem for large apps.

Till now...I have used the Slim Framework only for creating RESTFUL services outside my web apps.

I am using Slim Framework to create APIs for a PHP project. Now, I have an install of Slim up and running fine. I have my routes talking to the database and doing what they're supposed to do, generally. My question has to do with modularizing the code. At the moment, all my routes are defined in my index.php file in the root directory. I would very much like to separate these out, say into a /controllers folder.

As I liked the way Slim makes pretty good URLs...I am wondering if it is possible to use Slim as my app architecture ...and let all my pages or APIs be accessible through the Slim index.php.

Comment: You might check one of the Slim skeletons for inspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes pretty easily here are the steps I have taken on a recent project.

First lets say your have a HomeActionController

```
class HomeActionController {

    //The below line I have moved into an abstract Controller class
    public $view = null;

    //This is using Slim Views PhpRenderer
    //This allows for a controller to render views can be whatever you need
    //I did not like the idea of passing the whole DC it seemed overkill
    //The below method I have moved into an abstract Controller class
    public function __construct(\Slim\Views\PhpRenderer $view = null){        
        if($view != null){
            $this->view = $view;
        }
    }  

    //View could be any action method you want to call it.
    public function view(Request $request, Response $response, array $args){
         $data['user'] = "John Doe";
         return $this->view->render($response, 'templates/home.php', $data);
    }
}
```

Now you need to be able to call an instance of this controller from a route so you need to add the controllers you have to the DC

Where ever you are creating your instance of slim you will need to get the DC and add an instance of your controller:

```
$app = new \Slim\App($config['slim']);

// Get Dependency Container for Slim
$container = $app->getContainer();

$container['HomeActionController'] = new Controller\HomeActionController($container['view']); //Notice passing the view
```

As a note the above instantiations could have been a closures but I did not see the point at the time or making them. Also, there are ways to lazy load that I have not explored yet see [here](http://nesbot.com/2012/11/5/lazy-loading-slim-controllers-using-pimple) for more information.

Now the last thing you need to do is be able to call these on the routes which is not a huge challenge.

```
$app->get('/home', 'HomeActionController:view');
```

Granted you cannot have an action with parameters but I have not had an issue just passing them along in the request and then getting them from there.

Comment: Which Slim version are you using.

Comment: I am on the latest 3 something.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a app with no framework, then i would recommend looking through this small github repo:
https://github.com/PatrickLouys/no-framework-tutorial

It goes through with you settings everything up in terms of routing, plus would make everything go through the index.php in a public folder like your asking.